# How to list even numbers in erlang using recursive functions?

Tags: recursion, erlang

How to generate even numbers in this way using *recursive* functions in Erlang.

Note: The length of the output list is the input of the function `func`

Example:

```
> mod:func(5).
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many ways to do that in erlang, I suggest:

1. with sequence generators

   ```
   doubles(Number)->
       lists:seq(2,Number*2,2).
   ```
2. with list comprehensions

   ```
   doubles(Number)->
       [X*2 || X <- lists:seq(1,Number)].
   ```
3. the recursive way

   ```
   doubles(Max)->
       doubles(1,Max).
   doubles(Max,Max)->
       [Max*2];
   doubles(Val,Max)->
       [Val*2]++doubles2(Val+1,Max).
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example module:

```
-module(even_numbers).   
-export([get_first_n/1]).   

get_first_n(Count) -> 
  get_first_n(Count, 2). 

get_first_n(1, Current) -> 
  [Current]; 

get_first_n(Count, Current) ->
  [Current] ++ f(Count - 1, Current + 2).
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple and natural Erlangish way:

```
func(N) when is_integer(N) ->
    func(2, N).

func(X, N) when N > 0 ->
    [X | func(X+2, N-1)];
func(_, _) -> [].
```

Answer (score 1):

For me tail-recursive way is more natural Erlang way:

```
func(N) when is_integer(N) andalso (N >= 0) ->
  func(N, 1, []).

func(0, _, Acc) ->
  lists:reverse(Acc);
func(N, I, Acc) ->
  func(N - 1, I + 1, [I*2|Acc]).
```